# Unable to post data to WCF service from iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am trying to post data to WCF service from iPhone Application but somehow service doesn't seems to be call through the iPhone. I received a Status Code = 999.

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://192.168.1.192/MSservice/SecureRegistration";

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:
              [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *postData = [bodyData stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSError *errorReturned = nil;
NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&errorReturned];
if (errorReturned)
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@", errorReturned.localizedDescription);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Data %@", data);
    NSString *responseString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response %@", responseString);
}
```

Comment: bodyData contains plain xml string with parameters.

<RegistrationRequest><UserName>test</UserName><FullName>testing</FullName><EmailId>test@gmail.com</EmailId><MobileNo>9123567787</MobileNo><Password>test</Password></RegistrationRequest>